# React - Issue with syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to test React out for myself. I got a simple "Hello World" message outputted successfully, so I tried taking this a step further and loop through data.

I'm getting a "waiting for roots to load…to reload the inspector” error, which after Googling tells me I have an issue with my syntax. I just can't find it... so your help is much appreciated!

```
var data = [
    {perc:"2.2%", year:"5"},
    {perc:"3.2%", year: "7"} 
]

var Rates = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <RateList data={this.props.rates} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Rate = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>{this.props.percent}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var RateList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    { this.props.data.map(function(rate){
                        return <Rate percent={rate.perc} />
                    }) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Rates rates={data} />, document.getElementById("wow"));
```

Comment: Probably not your problem, but doesn't the `map` callback need a `return`?

Comment: @torazaburo That's actually what the tutorial I followed had, but I tried to simplify the example to figure out the issue. I guess I might have to add the return back in if it's necessary?

Comment: The `return ` is necessary unless you're using a one-statement arrow function, like `this.props.data.map(rate => <li>{rate.perc}</li>)` (then it's implicit)

Comment: I'm no react expert, and there may be better ways to debug, but I would just adopt the old divide-and-conquer, binary search approach, which is removing things until it stops breaking. The last thing you removed was the problem.

Comment: Are you sure there exists an HTML element with the `id` "wow"?

Comment: @Mikke Turns out there's actually a word for that, it's called "concise body form".

Comment: I added the return back to the map callback in my example.

Comment: @Mikke Yeah, my "wow" id exists.

Comment: @torazaburo The divide and concur method is always the best. For some reason it always just breaks for me at the RateList class. Nothing I can do can explain why.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't know what I just did but it started working.... funny how things like this works. All your help was really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could simplify a little.

```js
var data = [
    {perc:"2.2%", year:"5"},
    {perc:"3.2%", year: "7"} 
]

var RateList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    { this.props.rates.map(function(rate){
                        return <li>{rate.perc}</li>
                    }) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RateList rates={data} />, document.getElementById("wow"));
```

Comment: it should be rates props instead of data in your case )